# Make radio button switch div visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 radio buttons.

- Clicking radio button 1 should display `p_div1` and hide
  `p_div2` and `p_div3`
- Clicking radio button 2 should display `p_div2` and hide
  `p_div1` and `p_div3`
- Clicking radio button 3 should display `p_div3` and hide
  `p_div1` and `p_div2`

```html
<div class="" id="" style="width: 800px;height: auto;margin: 0px auto;border: 1px solid black;">
    <div class="" id="">
        <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="group1" />
        <input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="group1" /><
        <input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="group1" />
    </div>
    <div class="" id="p_div1" style="width: 398px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;display:none">
        <p> This is div 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="p_div2" style="width: 398px;float: left;border: 1px solid black; display:none">
        <p> This is div 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="p_div3" style="width: 398px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;display:none">
        <p> This is div 3</p>
    </div>    
 </div>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    $("#Radio1").checked(function () {
        $("#p_div1").show();
        $("#p_div2").hide();
        $("#p_div3").hide();
    });
    $("#Radio2").checked(function () {
        $("#p_div1").hide();
        $("#p_div2").show();
        $("#p_div3").hide();
    });
    $("#Radio3").checked(function () {
        $("#p_div1").hide();
        $("#p_div2").hide();
        $("#p_div3").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So what is your question, and what problems are you having?

Comment: can u understand now ?

Comment: I understood as soon as I saw it (there is no jquery function named `.checked()` but you have to explain it in your question :)

Comment: You might want to look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1L9zufro/)

Comment: check my answer is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch a different event. Try your javascript like this:

```
$("#Radio1").change (function () {
        $("#p_div1").show();
        $("#p_div2").hide();
        $("#p_div3").hide();
    });
$("#Radio2").change (function () {
        $("#p_div1").hide();
        $("#p_div2").show();
        $("#p_div3").hide();
    });
$("#Radio3").change (function () {
        $("#p_div1").hide();
        $("#p_div2").hide();
        $("#p_div3").show();
    });
```

Comment: I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2Lj0w7/. Is your code different than this? The code inside the event listener is never executed?

Comment: hey do i wanna add any script file  ? for this

Comment: Try to catch an event of the radio group instead of each button to see if this works. Updated fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2Lj0w7/1/

Comment: $(window).on('load', function() { });   this is what i missed of

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type:'radio']").change(function () {
$("#Radio1").checked(function () {
        $("#p_div1").show();
        $("#p_div2").hide();
        $("#p_div3").hide();
    });
    $("#Radio2").checked(function () {
        $("#p_div1").hide();
        $("#p_div2").show();
        $("#p_div3").hide();
    });
    $("#Radio3").checked(function () {
        $("#p_div1").hide();
        $("#p_div2").hide();
        $("#p_div3").show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type:'radio']).change(function () {
  if($("#Radio1").is(:checked)) {
     $("#p_div1").show();
     $("#p_div2").hide();
     $("#p_div3").hide();
  }
  if($("#Radio2").is(:checked)) {
     $("#p_div1").hide();
     $("#p_div2").show();
     $("#p_div3").hide();
  }
  if($("#Radio3").is(:checked)) {
     $("#p_div1").hide();
     $("#p_div2").hide();
     $("#p_div3").show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `value` attribute to radio buttons. The event here is `change`, also add class to the divs for easy access.

```js
$("input[name='group1']").on('change',function() {
  var show = $(this).val();
  $(".p_div").hide();
  $("#p_div" + show).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="" style="width: 800px;height: auto;margin: 0px auto;border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="" id="">
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="group1" value="1" />
    <input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="group1" value="2" />
    <input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="group1" value="3" />
  </div>
  <div class="p_div" id="p_div1" style="width: 398px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;display:none">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="p_div" id="p_div2" style="width: 398px;float: left;border: 1px solid black; display:none">
    <p>This is div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="p_div" id="p_div3" style="width: 398px;float: left;border: 1px solid black;display:none">
    <p>This is div 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Atif and dchar have provided to good and fully functioning answers. However, I would like to recommend a more general approach that will work with any number or divs and radio buttons. This can be done using a custom `data-*` attribute.

First, you need HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="group1" data-show-div="p_div1" />
    <input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="group1" data-show-div="p_div2" />
    <input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="group1" data-show-div="p_div3" />
</div>
<div class="controlled-by-group1" id="p_div1">
    <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div class="controlled-by-group1" id="p_div2">
    <p>This is div 2</p>
</div>
<div class="controlled-by-group1" id="p_div3">
    <p>This is div 3</p>
</div>
```

Two things (apart from removing things not necesarry for the example) have changed here. First, all the radio buttons has a `data-show-div` attribute set to the ID of the div they should show. Secondly, all the divs have the class `controlled-by-group1`.

Now, the JavaScript:

```
// When one of the group1 radio buttons are changed...
$("input[name=group1]").change(function() {
    // Hide all divs that are controlled by group1.
    $(".controlled-by-group1").hide();
    // Get the ID of the div to show.
    var id = $(this).attr("data-show-div");
    // Show that div.
    $("#" + id).show();
});
```

As you can see the code gets shorter, but also more flexible. If you want to add a forth div you do not need to change the script. This script could also easily be modified to work with multiple groups or radio buttons and divs on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Try your javascript like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "p_div1") {
                $("#p_div2").hide();
                $("#p_div3").hide();
                $("#p_div1").show();
            }
            else if ($(this).attr("value") == "p_div2") {
                $("#p_div1").hide();
                $("#p_div3").hide();
                $("#p_div2").show();

            }
            else {
                $("#p_div1").hide();
                $("#p_div2").hide();
                $("#p_div3").show();

            }

        });
```